# Turn off or bypass SSL Certificate Verification in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ssl-certificate

I have my server certificates expired.

I want to bypass or turn off certs verification from my swift iOS app so i can test app features.

I need this just for testing, not for production of live app. so none concerned for security.

How can i achieve this in Swift iOS.

I am using Alamofire library for network requests.

How to achieve this.

Comment: for urlsession answer, [link] https://stackoverflow.com/a/59484010/6844940

Answer (score 3):

Put the below cod into info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: thanks @sanjeev. But this is already in my info.plist. It's not helping, i have tried again.

Comment: This is actually to allow app to call non-https services not to ignore self signed certificates.

Comment: This doesn't work for signed certs from a generated CA either.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class NetworkManager {

    static let shared = NetworkManager()

    var unsecure: SessionManager!
    var serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = ["unsecureSslHostname":.disableEvaluation]

    private init () {
        self.unsecure = { () -> SessionManager in
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
            return SessionManager(
                configuration: configuration,
                serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: self.serverTrustPolicies)
            )
        }()
    }
}
```

After that `NetworkManager.shared.unsecure` will return Alamofire SessionManager which can be used for send request to hosts with unsecured SSL certificates.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey Di for this. I am getting "Use of undeclared type" for "SessionManager" and "ServerTrustPolicy" using this code. I am using "Alamofire/Alamofire" "5.0.0-beta.2" through Carthage.

Comment: @SajidZeb do you try to use 4.x version?

Comment: @SajidZeb Are you sure you don't forgot to add import Alamofire?

Comment: no i don't want to degrade version. i am using 5. Also yes this line is at top.
import Alamofire

Comment: @SajidZeb I think issue happens because of Alamofire 5. SessionManager was renamed to Session with some other changes. Sorry I can't test on Alamofire 5 now.

Answer (score 0):

use this for your session configuration:

```
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = ["untrustedServer.com": .disableEvaluation]
let servertrustManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
sessionManager = SessionManager(configuration: configuration,serverTrustPolicyManager: servertrustManager)
```