# swift add ssl certificate to URLRequest

Tags: swift, ssl-certificate, urlrequest, cfnetwork

I'm trying to control my Phillips hue lights from my app.
Anyway they have an Api where we can control all of that.
The issue is that on the software Postman (to test) they say to disable "SSL Certificate Verification".
When I try to call with URLRequest in my app the same url which is: "https://<ip_address_of_Hue_bridge>/clip/v2/resource/device" well, I get this error:

> Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202
> NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “<ip_address_of_Hue_bridge>” which could put your confidential information at risk.

On the the Phillips Hue Developer portal they gave me something that look like the .cert certificate, but I don't know how to use it with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better way for you is to ignore the SSL certificate of the Hue. Give a look here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59484010/12277616

I strongly suggest you to not disable SSL connection in Xcode.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't really want to disable the SSL certificate